# jshint complains: 'Ember' is not defined

Tags: ember.js, jshint

I have a standard `Ember` `main.js` file, which starts like this:

```
this.App = Ember.Application.create({
    LOG_TRANSITIONS: true,
    VERSION: '1.0.0',
    ready: function () {
        console.log('App version: ' + App.VERSION + ' is ready.');
    }
});
```

Running this through `jshint` complains about Ember not being defined, which is true for this particular file in the server, during the deployment phase. Because of this, lots of error messages are shown.

`Ember` is made available in the browser by the `script` tag in `index.html`:

```
<script src="scripts/vendor/ember-1.0.0-rc.2.js"></script>
```

How can I tell `jshint` about `Ember`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The following should do it:

```
/*global Ember */
this.App = Ember.Application.create({
    LOG_TRANSITIONS: true,
    VERSION: '1.0.0',
    ready: function () {
        console.log('App version: ' + App.VERSION + ' is ready.');
    }
});
```

Found in [JS Hint Docs](http://www.jshint.com/docs/)

Comment: You mean adding `/* global Ember */` to `main.js`, before instantiating `this.App`? This is not working for me.

Comment: Then there must be something wrong with your JSHint setup. It works for me and as you see, i have taken it from the Docs.

Comment: I found the answer in the jshint mailing list: you can not put a space before `global`. It must be like this: `/*global Ember */`. Can you correct your answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: the space doesn't seem to be a problem anymore. I tried writing `/* global Ember */` and the error went away for me.

Answer (score 16):

If you're using the new ES6, for example from [ember-cli](http://iamstef.net/ember-cli/), you must import Ember:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
```

---

I was following [Evil Trout's Ember Reddit tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7twifrxOTQY) and saw the following error in the tests:

```
my-new-app/routes/subreddit.js should pass jshint.
my-new-app/routes/subreddit.js: line 3, col 16, 'Ember' is not defined.
```

adding the above line to the top of `my-new-app/routes/subreddit.js` passed the tests.