# Ember is not defined after minification

Tags: javascript, ember.js, brunch

Trying to compile a Ember.js application using the brunch command: `brunch b production`

When executing the public/index.html in a chrome, I'm told Ember is not defined. I've already seen [jshint complains: 'Ember' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15888975/jshint-complains-ember-is-not-defined)
but that doesn't seem to be helping me.

Not really sure what supporting information may be of help, but the app is *live* at http://reillyjoinery.acidic.co.nz/

This is my brunch config.js: http://pastebin.com/dYdveKpt

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not because of minification,

When I tried to investigate your site, I found you're *missing to add the `ember.js` library* file.

[image]

Also I checked whether you're using any CDN links but nope.  So add the file, the problem will be solved.

Comment: Shouldn't it be included in the vendor.js, though?